# sIFR header with inside span

Tags: css-selectors, sifr, header, html

I've got the following situation:

```
<h2>This text is <span>pretty awesome</span></h2>
```

I'm trying to give both a different style like this (only the css):

```
h2 { font-size: 21px; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 37px; height: 36px; text-align: right; margin-right: 10px; }
h2 span { font-size: 16px; color: #666666; text-transform: lowercase; }
```

Now just calling this like the following things doenst work and only displays the general H2 style:

```
sIFR.replace(headache, { selector: 'h2', css: ['.sIFR-root { stylesforh2 } '], wmode: 'transparent' });
sIFR.replace(headache, { selector: 'h2 span', css: ['.sIFR-root { stylesforspan } '], wmode: 'transparent' });
```

neither does this work:

```
sIFR.replace(headache, { selector: 'h2', css: ['.sIFR-root { stylesforh2 }, span { stylesforspan} '], wmode: 'transparent' });
```

I'm a sIFR firsttimer and I'm problably doing something silly wrong, but I cant figure it out. Can someone tell me how its done properly?

Using sIFRT version 3, revision 436.

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently it just wont work with span. Got it to with with `em`

Comment: Yea, Flash does that. You can give the `span` a class (`<span class="foo">`) and use that though (`.foo`).